# Linux shell: Adding dots to numerical outputs to make them more readable

Tags: linux, bash, numbers

This is a common output for **some numeric program** like Word-Count (`wc`):

```
$ wc MyLongFile.txt -l
985734902867 MyLongFile.txt
```

I was wondering about some way to **filter the numeric part** in order to become something a lot more readable like:

```
985.734.902.867 MyLongFile.txt
```

Many programs have some `-h` (for `human readable`) option, but it would be fine to know about some **generic method** that could be implemented in a function or alias... or at least typed in, if it is not very long.

I suppose the method would require to add a `.` each 3 numbers concatenated group, but starting from the right side.

Methods **not changing** the non-numeric parts are preferred. If possible, consider the possibility to have letters (or any other character) on the left side of the numbers to, like in:

```
ls -la
-rw-rw-r-- 1 luis luis  93342519 ene  1 00:22 tmp.txt
```

The best I have found until now is this `sed` command:

```
$ wc MyLongFile.txt -l | sed 's/\(^\|[^0-9.]\)\([0-9]\+\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1\2.\3/g'
985734902,867 MyLongFile.txt
```

...but, as you can see, it only work until thousands, and I am not very experienced on `sed`.

Thanks you a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this through Perl which uses a positive lookahead based regex.

```
perl -pe 's/(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3}){1,5}\b)/\1,/g' file
```

OR

```
wc MyLongFile.txt -l | perl -pe 's/(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3}){1,5}\b)/\1,/g'
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
7985734902867 MyLongFile.txt
734902867 MyLongFile1.txt
$ perl -pe 's/(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3}){1,5}\b)/\1,/g' file
7,985,734,902,867 MyLongFile.txt
734,902,867 MyLongFile1.txt
```

It's like a regex multiplication. Let me explain how it works. Consider this `7985734902867 MyLongFile.txt` as an example.

1. `\d{1,3}` Matches a single digit or two or three. If it's wrapped inside a capturing group, the corresponding digits not only gt matched but also it would be captured.
2. At first the regex engine would match the first digit  `7` and checks whether the digit 7 is followed by the digits which are the multiples of 3. So the digit 7 is followed by `12` digits again followed by a word boundary. 12 is a multiple of 3. So it captures the corresponding digit `7`. Here the word boundary `\b` is a must needed one which matches between a word character and a non-word character.
3. Next it checks the next digit 9, which is followed by 11 digits. So it won't capture only the digit `9`. Because we defined `\d{1,3}` ,  it takes two digits that is `98` and checks for the following digits. Because it is followed by 10 digits which aren't a multiple of 3. So it captures next digit also ie, `5` and then checks for the following digits. Now it is followed by a 9 digit number. So the corresponding three digits `985` would be captured. Likewise it goes upto the number which is followed by exactly three digits and a word boundary.
4. Replacing all the matched chars with `\1` ie, chars inside group index 1 plus a comma will give you the desired output.
5. You could increase the range count inside the positive lookahead for large numbers, like `(?=(?:\d{3}){1,10}\b`

Comment: Working flawlesly without touching non-numerical characters, tested for "wc" and "ls -la". Thanks you.

Comment: A useful tip: defining it like `alias DotThousands="perl -pe 's/(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3}){1,5}\b)/\1./g'"` you can do `ls -la | DotThousands` (or any other command).